# what am I doing wrong with if in python?

Tags: python, arrays, loops, if-statement, for-loop

I'm new to python, and maybe I ask a silly question, but I don't know why my code doesn't work... 
I have a delete method into a repository file which iterates through an array of cars, and if it finds a car that has the same id, deletes it.

This is my code:

```
def delete_car(self, carId):
        noOfCars = len(self.carsArray)
        for i  in range(0, noOfCars):
           print("Entered for")
           if (self.carsArray[i].get_id() == carId):
                print("found the id!")
                print(carId, self.carsArray[i].get_id())
                del self.carsArray[i]
                break
           else:
                print("didn't find any matching id", carId, self.carsArray[i].get_id())
```

and this is my output:

```
1.Cars menu
2.Clients menu
3.Rentals menu
0.Exit
```

Command:1

```
1.Show available cars
2.Add a car
3.Delete a car
4.Update car
5.Show cars by their manufacturer
6.Find a car
0.Exit
```

Command:3

```
1 Mustang Ford(A very nice muscle car)
2 Prius Toyota(A hybrid car)
3 Passat Volkswagen("The car of the people")
4 Logan Dacia(A Romanian made car)
```

Enter the id of the car you want to delete:2

```
Entered for
didn't find any matching id 2 1
Entered for
didn't find any matching id 2 2
Entered for
didn't find any matching id 2 3
Entered for
didn't find any matching id 2 4
```

I don't understand why does if continues to iterate after checking 2=2... it doesn't seem to be equal for python...

Any help?

Comment: Are you comparing a string with an integer? That is always False.

Comment: replace `print("didn't find any matching id", carId, self.carsArray[i].get_id())` with `print("didn't find any matching id %r %r" % (carId, self.carsArray[i].get_id()))` so we can have a better idea of what's happening

Comment: just a tip, use xrange instead of range, xrange is a generator and is relatively faster than range.

Comment: @mid, this only applies to python2

Comment: @Thomasleveil you know, I didnt know that, thanks man.

Comment: oh, great! I was comparing 2 different data types! Thanks a lot guys, and sorry for my silly question!